# Fitting a Normal Distribution to a set of Data

Tags: statistics

Problem: 
Fit a normal distribution to the following data:
x     f
462   98
480   75
498   56
516   42
534   30
552   21
570  15
588  11
606   6
624   2
Answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
n &=&  98 + 75 + 56 + 42 + 30 + 21 + 15 + 11 + 6 + 2 \\
n &=& 356 \\
u &=& \frac{98(462) + 75(480) + 56(498) + 42(516) + 30(534) + 21(552) + 15(570) + 11(588)  } { 356 } \\
 &&+ \frac{6(606) + 2(624)}{356} \\
u &=& \frac{ 109164 + 42(516) + 30(534) + 21(552) + 15(570) + 11(588)  } { 356 } \\
 &&+ \frac{6(606) + 2(624)}{356} \\
u &=& \frac{ 178350 } { 356 } \\
u &=& 500.98315 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we need to find the variance.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma^2 &=& E(x^2) - u^2 \\
E(x^2) &=&
 \frac{98(462)^2 + 75(480)^2 + 56(498)^2 + 42(516)^2 + 30(534)^2 +
    21(552)^2}{356} \\
 &+& \frac{ 15(570)^2 + 11(588)^2 + 6(606)^2 + 2(624)^2)}{356} \\
E(x^2) &=&
\frac{98(462)^2 + 75(480)^2 + 56(498)^2 + 42(516)^2 + 30(534)^2 +
 21(552)^2}{356} \\
&+& \frac{  11658852 }{356} \\
E(x^2) &=&
\frac{98(462)^2 + 75(480)^2 + 56(498)^2 + 42(516)^2 + 30(534)^2 +
 21(552)^2 + 11658852}{356} \\
%
E(x^2) &=&
 \frac{ 52085736 + 42(516)^2 + 30(534)^2 + 21(552)^2 + 11658852}{356} \\
E(x^2) &=&
 \frac{ 71823168 + 21(552)^2 + 11658852}{356} \\
%
E(x^2) &=& 252474.17 \\
%
\sigma^2 &=& 252474.17 - (500.98315)^2 = 1490.0534 \\
\sigma &=& 38.60121 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So I conclude we have a normal distribution with mean $500.98315$ and standard
deviation of $38.60121$.

However, the book's answer is:

Expected frequencies are $1.7$, $5.5$, $12.0$, $15.9$, $13.7$, $7.6$, $2.7$ and $0.6$ respectively.

I do not understand the book's answer.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear whether your observations are intended to be a
random sample or a population. If a sample, then one ordinarily
uses $n-1$ in the denominator of the sample variance. If a population,
then it is discrete (taking only ten distinct values), so clearly not
normal.

It is important to use the technical terminology precisely.

I have not checked your arithmetic; you should do so. I will assume for the moment that it is correct. So let's say this is a random sample
from a distribution assumed to be normal.

In that case, 'fit' means
to estimate the population mean $\mu$ by the sample mean (which I take to
be) $\bar X = 471.8$ and to estimate the population standard deviation
$\sigma$ by the sample standard deviation (which I take to be $S = 155.6.$

Then, the best fitting normal density curve is that of 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 471.8,\, \sigma =155.6).$

[image]

---

Note: When I tried to check your arithmetic for the sample mean (using R statistical software), I did not
get the same result you did:

```
v = c(462, 480, 498, 516, 534, 552, 570, 588, 606, 624)
f = c( 98,  75,  56,  42,  30,  21,  15,  11,   6,   2)
sum(f)
## 356       # NOT 378
sum(f*v)/sum(f)
## 500.9831  # NOT 471.8
x = rep(v, times=f)
mean(x)
## 500.9831  # again
sd(x)
## 38.65557
```

Please check my transcription of your data and your computations
to find the discrepancy.

*Addendum to Note per Comments:* A histogram using the default binning of R is shown below. From this histogram, I have doubts that the data are from a
normal population. Maybe assignment was to 'test whether data fit normal' rather than 'find best fitting normal'. Can't really guess from what you have posted.

[image]

Comment: The mean came out wrong because I had one number wrong when summing the frequencies. I will update the post a bit later. I understand your comment random sample or population but I am not sure. I am thinking that the difference of divided by $n$ or $n-1$ in this case is very small.

Comment: What do you think of the book's answer?

Comment: No clue about book's answ: 'Expected freq' usually has to do with chi-sq goodness-of-fit test. Maybe they want you to do such a test to see if data fit some normal dist'n well (which they obviously don't). Maybe they mean 'relative freq': In R the statment `round(f/sum(f),3)` returned 0.275, 0.211, 0.157, 0.118, 0.084, 0.059, 0.042, 0.031, 0.017, 0.006. // Difficulty is you give no context: what have you been studying recently? Have you seen chi-sq GOF tests? What is title of chapter where this problem occurs? What is _exact_ wording of problem?

Comment: Here is the exact wording of the problem: Fit a normal distribution to the data of Problem $5.98$. The problem is from the book Probability and Statistics by Schaum. I am using the second edition. The problem is from chapter 7 which is Tests of Hypotheses and Significance. The Chi-Square Test for goodness of Fit is covered in this Chapter.

Comment: Some help. I guess you asked to do a chi-squared GOF test. Some intervals must have been combined, because there are only eight expected frequencies and you had 10 intervals to begin.